# Does changing boot disk to SSD affects performance?

Tags: mysql, performance, ssd

We recently changed our production database disk to SSD.
To clarify, all data paths, caching, tmp, ... directory references in the MySQL configuration point to that database disk, now SSD.

The boot disk is still a regular HDD (in GC terms: Standard Persistent Disk). Will the change to a SSD boot disk affect overall performance of our database system?

The system is high read, low write; mostly analytics.

Comment: Depends on how often you reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analyze it this way.

- Every read or write to SSD will be (about) 10 times as fast as to/from HDD.
- Booting involves reading the OS into RAM -- perhaps more that a gigabyte of I/O.  So boot speed depends on the type of disk.
- Database reads/writes only touch the database directory tree, so their speed is depending on the type of disk it is on.
- There is *usually* no overlap between boot stuff and database stuff -- except that a simple installation throws them both into the same filesystem (hence same HDD or SSD).
- `/tmp` is sometimes put in its own filesystem.  This is configurable in the OS.  The database can be configured to use `/tmp` or some other location.  Hence, you may want to make sure MySQL's `tmpdir` is pointing to SSD.
- Most of MySQL's "caching" is under its own control.  So, I don't see an extra factor here.